# Classify Land Use Land Cover

Tags: remote-sensing, image-classification, ecognition

I am asked to classify an image (Landsat 7 scene) for 2 different time period one for the month of July (Image 1) and the other December (Image 2) as shown below.
[image]
*Image for the month of July*
[image]
*Image for the month of December*

However, I encountered a problem while classifying the image objects. The objects that I classified as low vegetation in first image is open soil in the second image.
The classified image for Image 1 using E-cognition is as shown:-
[image]

Image after classification for Image 1

So, how can this classification be carried out for the object image that is not permanent land cover and might changes with the change of season??? Is there any ruleset that can be applied in E-cognition software for this type of image scene?

Comment: What do you mean with first image and second image? Is it low vegetation in July and open soil in December? Then it's probably just the leaves that fall of the shrub layer that can not be detected (do you use an orthophoto or Lidar?), or maybe there was some kind of sucession process over the year. I would suggest to classify these areas that change over the season as vegetated areas.

Comment: @Radde1683 , Your answer seems reasonable. I have edited questions as looking after your constructive comments. Hope for your answers. But is there any ruleset for detection of LULC for 2 different images. Or I need to calculate area for each object classes for change detection.

Comment: You can perform change detection making use of Bi-temporal data you have. See relevant demonstration made available by eCognition TV, the official eCognition YouTube channel.